# Why current text is not updating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a life system in my game, but the test on the screen is not updating, although the variable is. I want my text to be updating also.

[image]

The LoseCollider Class

```
[SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI livesText;
[SerializeField] static int currentLives = 4;

public void Start()
{
    livesText.text = "Lives: " + currentLives.ToString();
    Debug.Log(currentLives);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (currentLives > 0)
    {
        currentLives--;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }

    if (currentLives <= 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
        currentLives = 4;
    }
}
```

I think you are right about DontDestroy is the issue.

It's from another script

```
public class GameSession : MonoBehaviour
{

    // config params
    [Range(0.1f, 10f)] [SerializeField] float gameSpeed = 1f;
    [SerializeField] int pointsPerBlockDestroyed = 83;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    [SerializeField] bool isAutoPlayEnabled;


    // state variables
    [SerializeField] int currentScore = 0;


    private void Awake()
    {
        int gameStatusCount = FindObjectsOfType<GameSession>().Length;

        if (gameStatusCount > 1)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        scoreText.text = currentScore.ToString();  

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Time.timeScale = gameSpeed;
    }

    public void AddToScore()
    {
        currentScore += pointsPerBlockDestroyed;
        scoreText.text = currentScore.ToString();
    }

    public void ResetGame()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public bool IsAutoPlayEnabled()
    {
        return isAutoPlayEnabled;
    }
}
```

I am completely now to unity. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I don't see where you ever update the `livesText.text` when you change the value of `currentLives`..?

Comment: @RufusL he reloads the Scene and the text gets updated in `Start`

Comment: it works for me btw ([gif](https://imgur.com/VXZ5Qog)) so there seems to be something you didn't tell us ;) Is the object maybe `DontDestroyOnLoad`? That would cause the `Start` to **never** get called again.

Comment: @derHugo, I think you are right about this, I updated the code. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

As I suspected you are using `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Your first script seems to be attached to the same object as `GameSession` or is in the hierarchy below it (a child).

This makes `Start` be **never** called again.

---

**But** you can register a callback to [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) in order to update the text:

```
public class GameSession : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ...

    private YourFirstScript yourFirstScript;

    // rather implement a Singleton pattern this way
    private static GameSession Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(Instance)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            return;
        }

        Instance = this;

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        // Add the callback
        // it is save to remove even if not added yet
        // this makes sure a callback is always added only once
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;

        yourFirstScript = GetComponentInChildren<YourFirstScript>(true);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // make sure to remove callbacks when not needed anymore
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    // called everytime a scene was loaded
    private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        scoreText.text = currentScore.ToString(); 

        // Since you made it public anyway simply call the method
        // of your first script
        // You shouldn't call it Start anymore
        // because now it will be called twice
        yourFirstScript.Start();
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

Note: It is also relevant that the `livesText` is also either `DontDestroyOnLoad` or is re-assigned after scene loading. Otherwise you'll get a `NullReferenceException` anyway.

---

> How do I reassign the `livesText`?

You could make `Instance` of `GameSession`

```
public static GameSession Instance;
```

it is a bit abusing the singleton pattern and kind of controverse .. but I think it is okey for fast prototyping.

and also make `levelText` in `YourFirstScript`

```
public TextMeshProUGUI levelText;
```

Then you could simply have a new component on the according `levelText` object like

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(TextMeshProUGUI))]
public class LevelTextAssigner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // you can reference this already in the Inspector
    // then you don't need to use GetComponent
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _text;

    // Is called before sceneLoaded is called
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_text) _text = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();

        // It is possible that the first time GameSession.Instance is not set yet
        // We can ignore that because in this case the reference still exists anyway
        if(GameSession.Instance)
        {
            GameSession.Instance.YourFirstScript.leveltext = _text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted the full GameSession Script, as you can see here is the Score and it's updaing in the game. I think you have a better view now, and could find an easier solution

Comment: How do I reassign the livesText?

Comment: @Light_Warrior Updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

Set TextMeshProUGUI via the "SetText" api. Doing `text = "something";` updates the backing field, where the value is stored, but does not necessarily trigger the GUI to update the text.

This has been a problem I noticed myself in the past, based on specific version of TextMeshProUGUI. It does not affect all versions of UGUI, so for some users this is not a problem. Looks like it most likely is in your case.

Comment: works for me  ([gif](https://imgur.com/VXZ5Qog)) so I guess the issue is another one